# ViewBox issue for SVG responsive button

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm creating a button with rounded corners using SVG (I have to use SVG).

So I succeed to make it responsive related to his parent element #btnTour which I put a width and a height on. But I always have a gap between this #btnTour and the path of my SVG I think it's related to the viewbox but after reading bunch of articles about it I still can't figured out how to solve my issue.

Thanks for your help.

```css
#btnTour{
  display: inline-block;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0;
  width: 192px; 
  height: 70px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#svgContainer{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  border: dotted 1px red;
 }

#btnTourText{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #2b5e9d;
  font-weight: 600;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<a id="btnTour" href="page2.php">

 <div id="svgContainer">

     <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 300 125" preserveAspectRatio="none">

         <path id="svgBtn" style="fill:none;stroke:#2b5e9d;stroke-width:2;"  d="M286.5,62.5C286.5,90.39099999999999,263.891,113,236,113C236,113,171.64499999999998,113,150,113C128.355,113,64,113,64,113C36.109,113,13.5,90.39099999999999,13.5,62.5C13.5,62.5,13.5,62.5,13.5,62.5C13.5,34.609,36.109,12,64,12C64,12,128.35500000000002,12,150,12C171.645,12,236,12,236,12C263.891,12,286.5,34.609,286.5,62.5C286.5,62.5,286.5,62.5,286.5,62.5C286.5,62.5,286.5,62.5,286.5,62.5"></path>         

     </svg>

 </div>

 <p id="btnTourText">Go on a Tour</p>
</a>
```

Comment: Finaly got my code accepted... None of your shortcut work I've to make all the indent one by one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you have to set the view box to fit the path ( eg. something like `viewBox="12.5 11 275 103"`); you can do it programmatically via js ( compute the bounding box to the to be fit svg element ) or set/get it from your preferred svg authoring app...

Comment: Thanks ! Next time should I make an SVG exactly the same size of my document on illustrator ?

Comment: Yes ( assuming exporting from ai to svg works the way it should ;) ), of course, it depends on what you want to ultimately achieve ...